# How to properly import constants defined in a different file in python

Tags: python

When I run `python3 my_calendar.py`, inside the directory `my_calendar_project`, everything seems to work fine. The problem appears when I run "`python3 -m my_calendar_project`", so I receive the following error message: `"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'constants'"`

Directory tree and the error message:

[directory tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GM1R.png)

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nC4t0.png)

```
from datetime import date

import constants
import functions
```

Comment: It would help to paste the text instead of images, and to include the traceback (or at least the line that does `import constants`.

Comment: @coutj The error msg image is nowhere to be found.

Comment: isn't `my_calender_project` is module, you can't use module like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made a minimal reproducible version of your question

```
foo
├── __init__.py  <--- <empty>
├── __main__.py  <--- from constants import x
└── constants.py <--- x = 1
```

The short answer is that when you invoke with `-m` it doesn't add `foo` to the python path, (it adds `.` to the path in both cases, and you are in a different directory).

```
/tmp/foo $ python __main__.py  # Fine
/tmp $ python -m foo  # Fails
```

You need to change this to be `foo.constants` if you want it to work as a package, which will keep it from working (without path manipulation) if you want to invoke it from its own directory.

```
sed -i foo/__main__.py 's/constants/foo.constants/'
/tmp/foo $ python __main__.py  # Fails
/tmp $ python -m foo  # Fine
```

Python packaging tools get around this in various ways, if you have a project you plan to maintain for a while I recommend `tox` or similar.

Comment: So I can't have both approach (package/scripting) working without making some modifications on my project, right? I found a tutorial that could be  interesting for this topic: https://realpython.com/pypi-publish-python-package/#different-ways-of-calling-a-package .  I think that use it as script makes more sense to me, thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't recommend it, but I had gotten used to a "I can execute individual scripts however I want" model in the past.  You can do this with a `if __name__ == '__main__':  import sys; sys.path.append('../../..')` type manipulation (before any package imports), and using full module imports everywhere.  You will be happier to learn the right way to do it though, it is probably a 2 hour investment that gives a lot of benefits